# Adding carons and diacritics to Greek letters in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

When writing in Microsoft Word, is there a way to put carons and similar diacritics above Greek letters like in Latin? Simply inserting them seems to place them slightly to the side, either left or right of the actual letter, but I'd like to put them above.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is you'd need to create your own font if you wanted greek symbols with diacritic marks.

[MS WORD's documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-to-add-language-accent-marks-in-word-3801b103-6a8d-42a5-b8ba-fdc3774cfc76) shows how to add these kinds of mark to your text, but they only work for specific letters

[image]

But you could create a font that incorporated the marks and switch between regular symbols and your fancy symbols.

Answer (score 1):

MS Word's documentation also talks about [inserting symbols](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-a-symbol-in-word-2a061ae9-5a6c-4407-b618-8dc3c9fd4f44), which can include any UTF-8 character or any character in a special font. I suggest investigating the different options here before going and inventing your own font.